# Convert ereg to preg_match with delimiters

Tags: php

I have found a script I use has stopped working because 'ereg' is no longer support in php...I did not write this script myself but can't for the life of me figure out where to put the delimiters.

I have changed the 'ereg' and 'ereg_replace' with 'preg_match' and 'preg_replace' respectively.

```
    function checkPostcode($toCheck) {



  $orig = $toCheck;



  // Permitted letters depend upon their position in the postcode.

  $alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                          // Character 1

  $alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                          // Character 2

  $alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkstuw]";                                   // Character 3

  $alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                     // Character 4

  $alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                             // Character 5



  // Expression for postcodes: AN NAA, ANN NAA, AAN NAA, and AANN NAA

  $pcexp[0] = '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'{0,1}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';



  // Expression for postcodes: ANA NAA

  $pcexp[1] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}[0-9]{1}'.$alpha3.'{1})([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';



  // Expression for postcodes: AANA NAA

  $pcexp[2] =  '^('.$alpha1.'{1}'.$alpha2.'[0-9]{1}'.$alpha4.')([0-9]{1}'.$alpha5.'{2})$';



  // Exception for the special postcode GIR 0AA

  $pcexp[3] =  '^(gir)(0aa)$';



  // Standard BFPO numbers

  $pcexp[4] = '^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$';



  // c/o BFPO numbers

  $pcexp[5] = '^(bfpo)(c\/o[0-9]{1,3})$';



  // Load up the string to check, converting into lowercase and removing spaces

  $postcode = strtolower($toCheck);

  $postcode = str_replace (' ', '', $postcode);



  // Assume we are not going to find a valid postcode

  $valid = false;



  // Check the string against the six types of postcodes

  foreach ($pcexp as $regexp) {



    if (preg_ma($regexp,$postcode, $matches)) {



      // Load new postcode back into the form element  

      $toCheck = strtoupper ($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches [2]);



      // Take account of the special BFPO c/o format

      $toCheck = preg_replace ('C\/O', 'c/o ', $toCheck);



      // Remember that we have found that the code is valid and break from loop

      $valid = true;

      break;

    }

  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiters should wrap regular expressions so it have to be placed in `$pcexp[0]` and `$pcexp[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The delimeters are a pair of characters at the start and end of the regex pattern string. The standard delimiter character is `/`, but others can be used instead if you prefer.

So, for example:

```
'^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$'
```

should be changed to:

```
'/^(bfpo)([0-9]{1,4})$/'
 ^                    ^
added this         and this
```

As you see above, I've added a `/` at the start and end of the string. You could use `#` or `~` or a variety of other characters for your delimiters if you prefer.

Be sure to escape any occurrences of the delimiter character within the string, or it will be seen as a closing delimiter.

Comment: Thanks...tried that but throwing up errors: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Given the error message you've got, you clearly *didn't* do what I said, because it's saying you're using a letter or a backslash as your delimiter. The delimiter I specified is a *forward* slash.

Comment: PHP's error message says you didn't. If you're sure you did, then I guess there's something more going on than you've told us. Try echoing the regex pattern immediately before the `preg_match` call, to see what value is actually being used. Either way, a bit of debugging work is your best bet here; the script is more complex than it needs to be, but not overly so. Try tracking through it with `echo` to see what's going on, to see where it breaks and with what values. Then write a small test program that just does that small bit of code, with the values given, and play with it until it works.

Comment: The developer I use is away and I know a bit but this is beyond me, this script has worked fine for a few years but all of a sudden it's stopped working and I have it on like 9 clients websites. I'm sure it's something to do with 'ereg' not being supported...is there anyway I can send you full file as it's probably something so small?

Comment: The error is complaining about the `preg_replace()` call. This also needs to have the delimiters added in the same way. Change `'C\/O'` to `'/C\/O/'`. The line I gave you in the answer was an example... **all** your regex patterns need delimiters adding, not just that one.

Comment: Yupp...tried that also and did not work, also tried adding this `if (preg_match('/' . $regexp . '/i', $postcode, $matches)) {` which I found elsewhere...and that don't work either :o(

Comment: I don't really have time to keep helping, but slow down and think about it before trying things. If you already added delimiters to the preg_match, then adding more will make it wrong again. At the very least, make sure you know which line the error is on and which lines are already working. The error you quoted was on the `preg_replace()` line, which means it must already have got past the `preg_match()`. Concentrate on the line where the error is happening. It's really not that complex.

Comment: The code I first posted is not complete, I have done all you have said but throwing up loads of errors after changing the 'ereg' like:  'Undefined variable' and 'Trying to get property of non-object in'...anyway thanks for your help, I officially give up! will have to find a php coder

Comment: hm yes, given what you just said, I think that's the best thing you can do right now. You need someone who can actually look at the code and run it. The problem is becoming much too broad to be able to help via a site like SO.